# Can a read-only user in postgreSQL read the files in system?

Tags: postgresql

I have a read-only user in postgreSQL, is it possible to read the files with the user in query?

Answer (score 1):

There are the built-in functions `pg_read_file` and `pg_read_binary_file` to read files, which by default are only available to superuser, but the `EXECUTE` right can be granted to others. There is also `COPY ... FROM 'file'`, which can be used to read files from the database server into tables, but that is available only to members of the `pg_read_server_files` group or superusers.

So no, a user that didn't get any special privileges cannot read files from the database server.